# Identify the fraction of raster cells and listing all the cell values in every polygon

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, polygon, attribute-table

In ArcGIS 10 I have a netcdf file that maps the fractions of cropland in the world from 1700 to 2007. I extracted the years that I needed as raster layer format (continuous data from 0 to 1) and now, using a shapefile of the world's countries, I would like to identify every raster's cell inside every country (possibly in a table format where I find id of the cell, country name, fraction cultivated). Is it even possible to do it? Moreover I would like to have also the fraction of cell belonging to a country and the fraction belonging to another one (i.e. in the boundary).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would summarize your raster data by country using the [Zonal Statistics as Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm) tool, but as you want to know the proportion of cell area in a country then you need to take a different approach. I would convert your raster into a polygon dataset and then run that through the Union tool with your country boundary dataset. From that dataset you can determine the area of cell in each country.

Be aware that cells in your raster that are adjacent to each other with the same value will dissolve into a single larger polygon rather than maintain their original cell extent.

If you need to maintain the cell then you need to go down another route and convert your cells into points and then convert those back into a raster using a unique row ID as the value then convert back into polygon. This approach works OK with smaller rasters as you'll quickly create a huge number of polygons. If that is an issue you'll need to work at a country level rather than globally.